# Rails 4 current_user (gem devise) acess into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model

I would like add condition in my model (ForumsTopic) and i need the current user value.

Here's my ForumsTopic.rb :

```
class ForumsTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :forum
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :topic_track, ->(user){where(user_id: current_user.id)}, :class_name=> 'ForumsTrack'
 has_many :forums_messages
```

on the line with "has_one :topic_track[...] i have one condition with user_id = current_user.id.

But, how i can make that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a scope for that in the `ForumsTrack` model.

```
class ForumsTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :topic_track, :class_name=> 'ForumsTrack'
end

class ForumsTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user, -> (user) { where(user: user) }
end
```

I would then pass the `current_user` from a place it is available (controller, service_model, etc).

Comment: Thanks it's work ! but just an error with your code on ForumsTrack : `scope :for_user, ->(user){ where(user: user) }` (arrow before "(user)")